# Entity Framework Core execute multiple times

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have these 3 tables.

1. Product (i store some basic info about the product, like a sku, gtin, etc.)
2. Brand (storing some basic info about the brand, which is left joining the product)
3. SuplierSpecs (left joining the product, and every product could have multiple suppliers and different SuplierId's like sku etc.)

Now I get a keyword from the user, and I want to give back distinct records where the product gtin, or sku, or any supliers sku contains the keyword.

So here is my query:

```
var query = from p in _productRepository.Table
            join s in _suplierProductSpecsMapRepository.Table on p.Id equals s.ProductId into sp
            from z in sp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join c in _brandRepository.Table on p.Brand.Id equals c.Id into br
            from b in br.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where (p.Gtin.Contains(Keyword) || p.Sku.Contains(Keyword) || z.SupplierSku.Contains(Keyword))
            select new { p.Gtin, p.Name, b.Name };
return query.Distinct().Take(10);
```

I call the query from the controller, the above code is in a service:

```
var products = _productService.GetProductsByKeyword(keyword);
var response = products.ToList();
return Json(products);
```

Now when I call the `.toList()` it takes 6-7 seconds to execute, I have around 250K products, and 450K supplier specs.

I looked in the output window, and I saw that it is executing around 8 queries, no idea why, and some are even the exact same queries.

Here is my output window:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (846ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2018-06-20T21:34:52.5602316Z","tags":{"ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.name":"POST Product/*****","ai.internal.nodeName":"***","ai.operation.id":"c690445c-4f21f9b370fd66f2","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"***","ai.operation.parentId":"|c690445c-4f21f9b370fd66f2.","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (846ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nSELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]\r\nFROM [Products] AS [p]\r\nLEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]\r\nLEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]\r\nWHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","parameters":"@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command","DeveloperMode":"true","commandText":"SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]\r\nFROM [Products] AS [p]\r\nLEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]\r\nLEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]\r\nWHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","elapsed":"846","commandTimeout":"30","commandType":"Text"}}}}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (846ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command Information: 20101 : Executed DbCommand (846ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor:Information: Executing JsonResult, writing value Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType44`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]].
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2018-06-20T21:34:52.5661523Z","tags":{"ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.name":"POST Product/*****","ai.internal.nodeName":"***","ai.operation.id":"c690445c-4f21f9b370fd66f2","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"***","ai.operation.parentId":"|c690445c-4f21f9b370fd66f2.","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executing JsonResult, writing value Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType44`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]].","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"Executing JsonResult, writing value {Value}.","Value":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType44`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]]","CategoryName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor","DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor:Information: Executing JsonResult, writing value Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType44`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]].
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor Information: 1 : Executing JsonResult, writing value Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType44`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]].
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (856ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2018-06-20T21:34:54.4290810Z","tags":{"ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.operation.name":"POST Product/*****","ai.internal.nodeName":"***","ai.operation.id":"c690445c-4f21f9b370fd66f2","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"***","ai.operation.parentId":"|c690445c-4f21f9b370fd66f2.","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Executed DbCommand (856ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']\r\nSELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]\r\nFROM [Products] AS [p]\r\nLEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]\r\nLEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]\r\nWHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"{OriginalFormat}":"Executed DbCommand ({elapsed}ms) [Parameters=[{parameters}], CommandType='{commandType}', CommandTimeout='{commandTimeout}']{newLine}{commandText}","parameters":"@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command","DeveloperMode":"true","commandText":"SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]\r\nFROM [Products] AS [p]\r\nLEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]\r\nLEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]\r\nWHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","elapsed":"856","commandTimeout":"30","commandType":"Text"}}}}
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command:Information: Executed DbCommand (856ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command Information: 20101 : Executed DbCommand (856ms) [Parameters=[@__p_3='?', @__Keyword_0='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_1='?' (Size = 4000), @__Keyword_2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@__p_3) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]
LEFT JOIN [Brands] AS [c] ON [p].[BrandId] = [c].[Id]
WHERE (((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_0, [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_0 = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_1, [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_1 = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX(@__Keyword_2, [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR (@__Keyword_2 = N''))
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action ***.Controllers.ProductController.*** (***) in 3737.9813ms
```

Can anyone help me figure that one out?

Am i correct here its getting executed around 8 times in order to get back the result? and if so, why? if i take the same query and i execute it in my db it takes less than a second,

Here is the code i used in sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Top(10) [p].[Gtin], [p].[Name], [c].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
Left JOIN [SupplierSpecs] AS [s] ON [p].[Id] = [s].[ProductId]
Left Join [Brands] as [C] ON [p].BrandId = [c].Id
WHERE (((CHARINDEX('test', [p].[Gtin]) > 0) OR ('test' = N'')) OR ((CHARINDEX('test', [s].[SupplierSku]) > 0) OR ('test' = N''))) OR ((CHARINDEX('test', [p].[Sku]) > 0) OR ('test' = N''))
```

but in code it takes around 7 seconds.

Comment: There's a lot of redundancy in ef-core's logging if you don't filter it. In realty there's only one query. You can check with SQL server profiler.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i edited my post, included the sql code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo here:

```
var products = _productService.GetProductsByKeyword(keyword);
var response = products.ToList();
return Json(products);
```

You are making the serializer call the database again instead of using the materialized results of `response`. Also, you should really be using `ToListAsync` here:

```
var products = await _productService.GetProductsByKeyword(keyword).ToListAsync();
return Json(products);
```